# How to copy all fields from one object to another, but only when destination value is NULL

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to merge one object into another in a generic way that can be used repeatedly for other more complex objects. I only want the NULLs to change.

ie. merge sourcePerson and detinationPerson to get resultingPerson (below)

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

var sourcePerson = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Bill",
    LastName = "Smith",
    Age = 43,
    Address = "123 Some Street"
};
var destinationPerson = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Barbara",
    LastName = null,
    Age = 41,
    Address = null
};
var resultingPerson = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Barbara",
    LastName = "Smith",
    Age = 41,
    Address = "123 Some Street"
};
```

I've tried Automapper, but can't seem to configure it properly. I feel like the following should work. Help?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
Mapper.Map(sourcePerson, destinationPerson);
```

Comment: Did it work then? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Please look here, it looks like you have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359634/c-sharp-automapper-conditional-mapping-based-upon-target-value

Comment: @Matt Is changing your mapping to: `Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(person => person.DestinationValue == null));` works?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks IronGeek and tutok.

Yes, the following works:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>()
      .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(person => person.DestinationValue == null));
```

Comment: Is this really a solution? You still need to name all the fields you want to overwrite: i.e., `DestinationValue` needs to be a property of `Person`

Answer (score 0):

Your can use reflection like this:

```
   public static T Merge<T>(T source, T destination)
     {
         var returnvalue = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T));
         foreach (var field in destination.GetType().GetProperties())
         {
             field.SetValue(returnvalue,
                 field.GetValue(destination, null) == null ? field.GetValue(source) : field.GetValue(destination));
         }
         return returnvalue;
     }
```

I haven't tested this for other than simple DTOs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty keen to try out Automapper. If I can't get it to work for me, i'll go with your approach