# How do I ignore a property when I call .Map in automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I know I can ignore a property when creating the map like this

```
CreateMap<ClaimExposure, ClaimExposure>();
   .ForMember(x => x.Claim, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

but that's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking for a way I can do it when I map like this

```
_mapper.Map(claimExposureDto, claimExposure, opt => opt. ??)
```

And it only applies to this mapping instance. Is this possible?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# AutoMapper Conditional Mapping based upon target value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359634/c-sharp-automapper-conditional-mapping-based-upon-target-value)

Comment: No it doesn't! Re read my post please!

Comment: The answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859214/how-to-ignore-a-property-based-on-a-runtime-condition) from Aaron Wynn fixed this issue for me.